# How to find available workers given start and end time?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to come up with a way to find workers who are available between a time range.

Here's what my simple table looks like:

```
create table work_hours (
  worker_id bigint,
  day int check( day > 0 and day < 8),
  starts_at time,
  ends_at time
)
```

How can I find workers that might be working between say "12:00" and "15:30"?

I tried using the `BETWEEN` operator on starts_at, but how can I check the range because a worker might be working between "09:00" and "17:00" which is between the range I want?

Comment: Your question is inconsistent.  Do you want works who *are* or *are not* working during that time?  Does the day of the week matter?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has a sophisticated date/time function called [`OVERLAPS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-datetime.html).

The following query will give you ids of the workers that have no record in the `work_hours` table that overlap the 12:00 > 15;30 timeslot. This basically means that these workers are available all week long in the timeslot.

```
SELECT DISTINCT worker_id
FROM work_hours w
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM work_hours w1
    WHERE 
        w1.worker_id = w.worker_id
        AND (TIME '12:00:00', TIME '15:30:00') OVERLAPS (starts_at, ends_at)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inequalities.  This gives you more control over whether the boundaries are included or not included:

```
select w.*
from works w
where not exists (select 1
                  from worker_hours wh
                  where wh.worker_id = w.worker_id and
                        wh.starts_at < '15:30:00' and
                        wh.ends_at > '12:00:00'
                 );
```

This does not include the boundaries in the comparisons.  It also assumes that there is a separate table with all worker ids -- which seems reasonable.